# How to create a generic function to convert from interface to implementing class

Tags: typescript

I have a Rest API, and am deserializing the responses into plain Javascript objects.

I have classes that implement the interfaces that represent the Rest responses and have additional functionality.

For example

```js
interface IUser {
  FirstName: string;
  LastName: string;
}

class User implements IUser {
  private firstName: string;
  private lastName: string;

  public get FirstName(): string {
    return this.firstName;
  }
  public set FirstName(value: string) {
    this.firstName = value;
  }

  public get LastName(): string {
    return this.lastName;
  }
  public set LastName(value: string) {
    this.lastName = value;
  }

  // Extra Stuff
  public get FullName(): string {
    return `${this.FirstName} ${this.LastName}`
  }

  constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
}
```

What I would like to do, is implement a method in a shared base class, that will convert an interface to the class that implements it.

I tried using a generic type alias, but I get an error `? expected`, which doesn't make much sense to me.

I think this captures the general idea of what I had in mind.

```js
type extendedBy<TInterface, T> = T extends TInterface;
abstract class AbstractBaseModel {
    public fillFromInterface<TInterface extends extendedBy<TInterface, this>>(iface: TInterface): this {
      Object.assign(this, iface);
    }
}
```

User would extend `AbstractBaseModel`, and ideally it would be used something like this

```js
let apiUser = getUserFromApi(userId);
let user = User.fromInterface(apiUser);
```

Is anything at all similar to this currently possible in typescript? Or will I need each class to implement their own fromInterface method?

Comment: Your example is full of errors. Could you please share working example

Comment: Sorry, do you mean the missing closing paren on the constructor? Other than that, it is a working example.

The AbstractBaseModel portion is not, because that's the part the question is about. I'm trying to figure out if it's even possible to represent such a relationship in typescript.